# Retrofit POST and NodeJS

Tags: android, node.js, web-services, retrofit, retrofit2

I can't run my app with a success response. I am trying to make a sign up.
I got this response on onResponse in my activity:

"Response {protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://myip:8122/consumer/signup}"

I am not sure, but I think it's not sending the params.

I've tested it on PostMan and it works. I selected "POST" and I wrote this URL: http://myip:8122/consumer/signup?f=Maria&l=Lucia&e=marlucia@hotmail.com&p=pass123

On Postman it works successfully: {"status":"success","message":"created user"}

**My activity:**

```
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BonaService.BASE_URL_SIGN_UP)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        BonaService service = retrofit.create(BonaService.class);

        Call<ResponseInsertUser> callRegisterUser = service.registerUser("John", "Clark", "jclark@gmail.com", "vtnctrump");

        callRegisterUser.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseInsertUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseInsertUser> call, Response<ResponseInsertUser> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    // HERE!!!!
                    Log.i("TAG", "Error: "+ response.code());
                } else {
                    ResponseInsertUser body = response.body();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseInsertUser> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("TAG", "ERROR: "+ t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

**BonaService:**

```
public interface BonaService {
    String BASE_URL         = "http://myip:5000/";
    String BASE_URL_SIGN_UP = "http://myip:8122/";

    @GET("listRandom")
    Call<BonaCatalog> listCatalog();

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("consumer/signup")
    Call<ResponseInsertUser> registerUser(@Field("f") String f,
                                          @Field("l") String l,
                                          @Field("e") String e,
                                          @Field("p") String p);
}
```

**ResponseInsertUser:**

```
public class ResponseInsertUser {

    private String status, message;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

**My Node code:**

```
function insertUser(req, res, next) {
var first = req.query.f;
  db.any('insert into user(id, first_name, last_name, email, password, user_status_id) values((select max(id) from user)+1, $1, $2, $3, $4, 1)', [req.query.f, req.query.l, req.query.e, req.query.p])
    .then(function (data) {
      res.status(201).json({
        status: 'success',
        message: 'created user'
      })
    })
    .catch(function (err){
     res.status(400).json({
      status:'fail', 
      message: 'Error!', 
      test: first
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@Query` parameters, not `@Field` parameters since it's added to the URL using `?key=value&` syntax

Should be a quick change, but you may also want to remove `FormUrlEncoded`